# How can I identify Windows hosts on a subnet with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, tcp, udp, delphi-2010

I have an administrative application that I would like to be able to "discover" Windows hosts on the same, or user-specified, subnet. What do you believe is the best way to quickly discover if a range of hosts are online, using Delphi?

I considered pinging the hosts (possibly [using WMI and Delphi](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/making-a-ping-with-delphi-and-the-wmi/)), but I believe there may be a more reliable way. I am concerned that clients may be configured to not respond to ping requests. Using [nbtscan](http://www.unixwiz.net/tools/nbtscan.html), I can very quickly get a list of Windows hosts on my subnet:

```
nbtscan 192.168.1.0/24
```

I'd like to be able to replicate this functionality, but I am not sure where to begin. Currently I am using the [ICS component created by François Piette](http://www.overbyte.be) for Delphi 2010.

I welcome any suggestions.

Comment: +1 The default Windows 7 firewall configuration allows incoming connections on UDP 137 from any kind of network (domain, public, private) given the connection is from the "local subnet". I guess this should be very reliable for host detection. Arguably the same is true for ICMPv4; If anyone goes through the trouble of blocking ICMP, they might also block UDP 137.

Comment: Adding a TCP/IP tag could attract more answers. ... Basically, ICS, Indy, Synapse etc are able to do port checks by opening a socket connection (or trying it). Without knowing which ports are open, this is a trial and error type of task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, I found this project on Sourceforge that demonstrates how to perform a NetBios lookup on a single host using Indy components. I tested and this project works well with Delphi 2010. This could, of course, be modified to perform NetBios queries on a range of addresses.

[NBLookup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nblookup/)

```
unit uNbLookup;

interface

(************************************************************

  06-02-2007 - Petricca Antonio (antonio.petricca@gmail.com)

  Free for any purpose...

  Thanks to:

    Jim Halfpenny
    http://directory.fsf.org/security/misc/nbtstat.pl.html

************************************************************)

uses

  IdGlobal,
  IdUDPClient,
  SysUtils,
  Windows;

function NetBiosLookup(AAddress: PChar; AHostName: PChar; ATimeOut: Integer): BOOL; stdcall;

implementation

const
  NB_REQUEST = #$A2#$48#$00#$00#$00#$01#$00#$00 +
               #$00#$00#$00#$00#$20#$43#$4b#$41 +
               #$41#$41#$41#$41#$41#$41#$41#$41 +
               #$41#$41#$41#$41#$41#$41#$41#$41 +
               #$41#$41#$41#$41#$41#$41#$41#$41 +
               #$41#$41#$41#$41#$41#$00#$00#$21 +
               #$00#$01;

  NB_PORT    = 137;
  NB_BUFSIZE = 8192;

function NetBiosLookup(AAddress: PChar; AHostName: PChar; ATimeOut: Integer): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  Buffer    : TIdBytes;
  I         : Integer;
  RepName   : String;
  UDPClient : TIdUDPClient;
begin
  RepName   := '';
  Result    := False;
  UDPClient := nil;

  if not Assigned(AHostName) then
    Exit;

  try
    UDPClient := TIdUDPClient.Create(nil);
    with UDPClient do begin
      Host := Trim(AAddress);
      Port := NB_PORT;

      Send(NB_REQUEST);
    end;

    SetLength(Buffer, NB_BUFSIZE);
    if (0 < UDPClient.ReceiveBuffer(Buffer, ATimeOut)) then begin

      for I := 1 to 15 do
        RepName := RepName + Chr(Buffer[56 + I]);

      RepName := Trim(RepName);
      StrPCopy(AHostName, RepName);

      Result := True;
    end;

  except
    Result := False;
  end;

  if Assigned(UDPClient) then
    FreeAndNil(UDPClient);
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you use a scanner like [nmap](http://nmap.org) for this.

And if you can not for any reason you can read about how they do that.

Check [Remote OS Detection](http://nmap.org/book/osdetect.html) and the [TCP/IP Fingerprinting Methods Supported by Nmap](http://nmap.org/book/osdetect-methods.html)
Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd prefer to do this without external tools. Additionally, the primary focus of the program I am working is *not* network detection. I'm hoping to add this as an aid to administrators to simply identify alive hosts on specified subnets.